# Loading image properly in listview

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview with image in list item. I am using a custom adapter for listview. I am using AsyncTask to download the images for each list item in the adapter. Code of my custom adapter:

```
public class AdapterUcomment extends ArrayAdapter<UserModel> {


public AdapterUcomment(Activity context, List<UserModel> list) {
    super(context, R.layout.layout_comment_item, list);
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
}

class ViewHolder {
    protected TextView text1, text2, text3;
    protected ImageView imagev;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = null;
    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
        view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.layout_comment_item, null);
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtv_uname);
        viewHolder.text2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtv_comment);
        viewHolder.text3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtv_cmntTime);
        viewHolder.imagev = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgv_upic);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else {
        view = convertView;
    }
    positionPic = position;
    final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    String uname = list.get(position).getUname();
    String ufbid = list.get(position).getUfbid();
    String ucomment = list.get(position).getUcomment();
    String ucomment_time = list.get(position).getUcomment_time();


    holder.text1.setText(Html.fromHtml(uname));
    holder.text2.setText(Html.fromHtml(ucomment));
    holder.text3.setText(Html.fromHtml(ucomment_time));

    // downloading the image using AsyncTask

    new UserPic(position, ufbid, holder.imagev).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);

    return view;
}


public class UserPic extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    String ufbid = null;
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    ImageView imageView;
    int pos = 0;
    public UserPic(int pos, String ufbid, ImageView imageView) {
        this.ufbid = ufbid;
        this.imageView = imageView;
        this.pos = pos;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        URL imageURL = null;
        try {
            imageURL = new URL(".......");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            bitmap  = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageURL.openConnection().getInputStream());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        super.onPostExecute(s);

    }
}
```

Everything seems to be working fine at the first glance like this:
[image of listview with properly loaded images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cNvN.png)
But the problem begins when i scroll down to the last item and then again scroll up to the first item then the first list item image disappears like this: [image of listview with improperly loaded image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiNvl.png) 
So how can i get rid of this and load the images properly in the listview properly?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please use image loader library. link: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: Question was asked bazillion times ... It because view reusing ... 1. getView called with position 1 you are starting asynctask1 2. getView is called again with position 2, the view from point 1 is reused and you are starting asynctask2 ... 3. asynctask2 is finished and right image is set 4. asynctask1 is finished and sets wrong image ... **the easy solution(not for production app) store URL as tag in imageview compare it with URL passed to AsyncTask before setting the bitmap ... if it's different do not set**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an image loading library like Picasso or Glide for loading images in to a listview. Also, have you considered using a recyclerview?

Here is more information on Picasso:
http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: I am using Picasso library but still getting the same error. Any idea?

Comment: finally got rid of this problem by using Recyclerview and Glide library